# Zoomable timeline with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, chap-links-library

I am working on making something like this: http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/

It's a zoomable timeline for calendars and such. I began with UIScrollView, but soon realised that this will be a huge hassle. I only found [This repo](https://github.com/lukescott/TimelineView), it looks bad, and its vertical. In addition its not zoomable.

This isn't too rare of a user interface object, so i suspect there are some repo for it that i'm not finding. If there is, can someone please link it?

If not, it would be great if someone could explain me how I can make one myself, or explain something, just give me some insight and get me motivated. (I'm a newbie programmer, help is good)

-Do i have to handle zooming with CA and path drawing instead of UIKit?

-Is UIScrollView more suited for this than say, UICollectionView, or just a custom made UIControl?

-How do I make scrollviews zoomable only horizontally?

Apologies for the horrible question.

Comment: Did you find an solution?

Comment: @ChrisBeeson nope. :( gave up and stalled the project pretty much

Comment: I ended up creating my own solution for this.  Check out 'action log' on the App Store.  PM me if you are interested in using it.

Comment: Hey Chris B, I checked out your app, looked pretty cool. I'm not sure how to PM you (don't think Stackoverflow allows it?) but is your solution open source or would we need to pay for it? Thanks! Minh

Comment: I came across https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Listings/StreetScroller_InfiniteScrollView_m.html which helps for the horizontal infinite scrolling. Still need to figure out the zoom part though...

Comment: Hi @Chris, did you release the source code somewhere? I'm really interested in the horizontal timeline for controlling audio... Thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroIván I ended up making my only solution to this, but it took a long time and I'm not open sourcing it at the moment.  Check out Action Log on the app store to see what I came up with. Happy to discuss further if you wish...

Comment: @Chris thanks... looks like I'm going to implement it from scratch. May I ask... how did you do it? Subclassed UIScrollView?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I built an infinite scrolling UIScrollView (google it) , this then gave me indexed views that allowed me to calculate between point, zoom level and timecode frame.